# Algebraic equation problem - finding $x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, exponentiation

$$(x^2 +100)^2 =(x^3 -100)^3$$

How to solve it?

Comment: That depends. If you're looking for real roots, there is only $x=5$. For complex roots, you may find two of them easily ($-2 \pm 4i$), but the others seem to be more difficult.

Comment: By the way, for 5, it's rather easy since $5^2+100=125=5^3$ and $5^3-100=25=5^2$.

Comment: expand both sides of the equation, bring everything to one side, try horner?

Comment: [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net) gets $x = 5, -2 \pm 4 i$ and a leftover factor $x^6 + x^5 + x^4 - 199 x^3 - 99 x^2 + 10100$.

Comment: Ez a kömalból van

Comment: First, what kind of $x$ are you looking for? Integer, real, complex? The answer will be different.

Comment: Solve this over the real numbers

Comment: A nice solution is proposed [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/344686/solve-this-equation-x21002-x3-1003), by clark.

Comment: http://www.komal.hu/verseny/feladat.cgi?a=honap&h=201303&t=mat&l=en

This really shouldn't be up here for a couple of weeks.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen as the other question has no satisfactory answer other than a graph.

Comment: @IshanBanerjee sry i just remembered i read the question once before but couldn't find it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]**hint** Define $f(x)=(x^2+100)^\frac{1}{3}$, notice that for $x\geq 0$
is increasing.

Compute its inverse function 
$$f^{-1}(x)=(x^3-100)^\frac{1}{2}$$

Where can $f$ and $f^{-1}$ intersect? Remember that the graph of $f^{-1}$ is the reflection of the graph of $f$ across the line $y=x$

Comment: They intersect when equation in title holds. But what then? I think you must add that $f'$ is increasing (but it's not), otherwise I can find increasing functions with has many intersections with $f^{-1}$ as you wish. Just take something like $x+\sin x$, for example.

Comment: @arbautjc but the point of intesections are in the line $y=x$ so you get to solve $f(x)=x$ instead, which can be solved

Comment: Oh, yes, silly me :-) Nice illustration btw.

Answer (score 3):

This is "cheating", of course:

[image]

Comment: I did not know this Google feature. Maybe it's not too important, WolframAlpha is probably much more suited to matematical needs, but anyway, it's nice. +1 for this.