# Solve this equation $ (x^3+100)^2 = (x^4-100)^3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Solve this equation $(x^3+100)^2 = (x^4-100)^3$

Comment: I am pretty sure it is a duplicate

Comment: Right : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/339106/algebraic-equation-problem-finding-x

Comment: Ok, solution is below, by clark. Funnily, it's marked as duplicate, but the solution is here, not in the linked question.